# CakePHP 3 Audit Log, working with admin routes?

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to work with [this CakePHP 3 plugin](https://github.com/rochamarcelo/cakephp-audit-log) which I think does exactly what I need it to do, but am struggling big time!  I'm new to CakePHP 3, composer and fiddling with routes etc (previously CakePHP 2.x and manual installation and never played with routes).

The plugin does not appear to be maintained any longer and the package does not exist when trying to install via composer, so I forked it and cloned the files to /plugins/AuditLog/

I've run updated my app composer.json file, loaded the plugin in my bootstrap.php, and run composer install on /plugins/AuditLog/ to load the dependencies from the plugin composer.json file (not sure if this is the right thing to do?)

In plugins/AuditLog/config/routes.php there is the following code

```
Router::plugin('AuditLog', function ($routes) {
    $routes->prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
    });
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

So a bit of searching in the CookBook and I read for the first time about 'prefix routing', which from what I can tell means I should be able to reach the pages via /admin/audit-log/audits (for example).

Not surprisingly, I get a missing controller error here

```
Error: Create the class AdminController below in file: src/Controller/AdminController.php
```

The instructions for the plugin don't mention anything about creating an admin controller, and there are no controller files anywhere in the plugin at all actually, despite there being views and models.

I'm really out of my depth here, can anyone help me untangle this?  Where/how to add which controllers and get them pointing to the right place?

Comment: For a bit of an update, I've been reading up and reinstalled the package by adding it to my app composer.json file as a repo using vcs - so thats a few problems fixed, but still no idea on the admin routing.  My fork is here: https://github.com/sanflynz/cakephp-audit-log

Comment: The URL would be `audit-log/admin/audits`, ie the plugin comes first, however it won't reach anything, as there are no controllers in the plugin. Maybe this is somehow tangled with [**`friendsofcake/crud`**](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud) which is required by the plugin, but I'm not familiar with CRUD. Maybe contact the author, or switch to a different plugin like [**`lorenzo/audit-stash`**](https://github.com/lorenzo/audit-stash), in whose favor the "original" `jippi/cakephp-audit-log` has been discontinued.